# how to print output from a while loop from a for loop for each iteration

Tags: python

I know I need a for loop, I am trying to print the input number(as a maximum) and then print the number of steps it took to reach 1. The current program prints the input number and the nember of steps for that input number, I need it to print every input number and corresponding steps for each number to 1 with related steps. If i input 2 it should say it 2 takes 1 steps then 1 takes 0 steps.

```
n = int(input('n? '))
n_steps = 0
num=n
while n > 1:
        n_steps+=1
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        else:
            n = n * 3 + 1
print(str(num) + ' takes ' + str(n_steps) + ' steps')
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What is an input example and what is the corresponding expected output (in a specific form and numbers, rather than a description)?

Comment: What do you mean by "*every input number*", there is only one input. If you want to run you code X times or indefinitely, use `for _ in range(X):` or `while True` to wrap all your code

Comment: Its the collatz count and a input example would be 5 and the output would be           1 takes 0 steps,
2 takes 1 steps,
3 takes 7 steps,
4 takes 2 steps,
5 takes 5 steps, each on there own line

Comment: put `num1=n` above the `n_steps=0` and put everything below `num1=n` into for loop that counts down from num1 and at the end of the iteration decrease `num`. that should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying to do something like this?

```
num = int(input('n? '))
for i in range(num, 0, -1):
    n_steps = 0
    n = i
    while n > 1:
        n_steps += 1
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        else:
            n = n * 3 + 1
    print(str(i) + ' takes ' + str(n_steps) + ' steps')
```

Comment: That is the answer I am looking for thank you, but one detail, I am assuming it has to do with the range function inputs. I need the answer in reverse. same numbers and output just in opposite print out order.

Comment: if you look at the `range` function it goes like this. `range(start,stop,step)`
so `range(5,0,-1)` will count from 5 down to 1. if you want opposite you can just use `range(5)` and it will count from 0 to 4. have fun with it. and if it helped i'm kindly asking to accept my answer

Comment: that works but I get the last printed line with 0 takes 0 steps, how can I eliminate that last output.

Comment: I just figured it out with your previous answer, thank you.... I just put for i in range(1,num+1): that gave me the output I wanted.

Comment: i copy pasted the exact code that i tested and it sure does not print 0 takes 0 because range is itself counting down to 1 and there's nothing that'll make `i` 0. please always try the provided code first as is, before modifying it.

Comment: Im not sure then, because after I changed the range to(1,num+1) it did just that (what I wanted) and how you wrote it  the 0 takes 0 steps was in there I will play with it more to under stand what is happening. But like I said with range(1,num+1) the 0 takes 0 steps disappeared.

Comment: are you sure when youre using my code you are using `range(num,0,-1)` letter by letter? please double make sure. because this is the way to use if you want your code to count from input number down to 1. with `range(1,num+1)` it will count from 1 up to your number and this is not what you stated in the question you said it needed to count down.
>If i input 2 it should say it 2 takes 1 steps "then" 1 takes 0 steps

Comment: also if i helped, could you please press that check mark that's next to my answer?

Comment: what you said was correct I just don't think I am explaining the answer I wanted correct.  ```num=int(input('n? '))
for i in range(1,num+1):
 n_steps=0
 n=i
 while n >1:
  n_steps+=1
  if n %2==0:
   n=n//2
  else:
   n=n*3+1
 print(str(i)+' takes '+str(n_steps)+' steps')```

Comment: I dont think it neede to count down just up.

Comment: i'm glad it worked for you. the technique used here is called `nested loops`, if you want to research more